# ASP.NET core app seems to throttle on Azure VM

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-virtual-machine, iis-10

I have a simple ASP.NET core web app deployed in IIS 10 hosted on an Azure VM.  The web app is known to use up as much memory as it can on certain operations it performs.  However, it seems something is throttling the use of memory when these memory-intensive operations are performed on the Azure VM.  Usually I have about 32GB memory allocated but the .net core host process is only using less than half of that.  I doubled the memory and reran the operations.  It only seems to use about 16GB-- when it goes a little higher, like 20GB, it then throttles down back to around 16GB.  When I run this web app locally, these memory-intensive operations utilize all available memory-- almost 64GB.

I checked the IIS settings on the Azure VM and they seem to be ok (no explicit throttling that I know of).  Was wondering what else could be limiting memory usage for my web app on Azure.

Comment: Could you share iis application pool adance setting about CPU usage, application pool recycling [iamge1](https://i.imgur.com/enfPVLe.png), and site adance setting about the limit [imge2](https://i.imgur.com/fy4cqEQ.png)?

Comment: Do you try [Memory-optimized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sizes-memory) virtual machine sizes?